# Laravel 4: how to make a column in an Eloquent model unique

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4

I have an Eloquent model `Article`, which has a column `title_url`, which should be unique, so there may not exist two `article`s with the same `title_url`. I don't want to return an error if two such `article`s already exist, I'd just like to change one's `title_url` silently. So instead of `super-article`, it's `title_url` would be `super-article-2`.

How can I do that in Laravel 4? Maybe using [mutators](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)? If yes, what would be the best way?

Bear in mind that I'd like the transformation of `title_url` happen silently and everytime it's necessary (update, insert).

Answer (score 1):

[In the lastest Beta 4 build of Laravel 4](https://github.com/laravel/framework), there is now an option to hook into create and update events:

> Added Model::creating(Closure) and Model::updating(Closure) methods for hooking into Eloquent save events. Thank Phil Sturgeon for finally pressuring me into doing this... :)

So this would seem to be the perfect fit for what you want. Just create a hook into the `create()` of your model, and create a simple function that checks for the `title_url` you are about to insert, and if it exists, change it to something else, then insert.